# Why is IDisposable instantly calling Dispose()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, idisposable

I have a web app (asp.net mvc 4) that uses IDisposable in another project in the solution. It all compiles and runs fine from visual studio (2012) but when using the browser to run the web app (using IIS 8 Express) an exception is throw.

My sealed class that uses IDisposable is in a using statement and the Dispose() method is called before any code in the using braces is reached i.e.

```
using (MySealedClass msc = new MySealedClass())
{
  //Code doesn't reach here. Dispose() is called beforehand
  //My code here . . . 
}
```

The constructor and it's dependent are:

```
private readonly IList<IntPtr> _intPtrList;

public MySealedClass()
{
    _intPtrList = new List<IntPtr>(); 
}
```

and so I don't think there should be any problem there. To test this I instantiated MySealedClass earlier in the code without using the using statement as follows:

```
MySealedClass msc = new MySealedClass()
```

The code can get past this point and I can then call methods on it.

I've seen some examples on MSDN where the using statement code is translated into a try catch pattern by the compiler, but I don't think this explains the error as the error happens before my main block code.

**Can anyone explain if the using statement is doing something extra? e.g. is it scanning the rest of the code block and if there is something it doesn't like, then calling the Dispose() method.**

My suspicion lies with IIS, Before, I had unsafe code errors (despite the right configuration in web.config) but I had forgotten to get IIS to run the app as x64. After doing that using regedit it was fine.

Additional info: In the using block, there is unsafe code and calls to external dlls using the [DllImport] attribute.

Many thanks

Comment: How have you established what's happening - what makes you believe that `Dispose()` is being called immediately and that control never entered the inside of the `using` block?

Comment: The code must enter the using block. You must have an exception being raised.

Comment: As it's only in the browser it doesn't work, I am throwing an exception on the first line below the using statement line and it doesn't reach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (MySealedClass msc = new MySealedClass())
{
  //Code doesn't reach here. Dispose() is called beforehand
  //My code here . . . 
}
```

is translated by the compiler to something quite similar to this:

```
MySealedClass msc = null;
try
{
  msc = new MySealedClass();
  //My code here . . . 
}finally{
  if(msc != null){
    ((IDisposable)msc).Dispose():
  }
}
```

The compiler does not check your code beforehand and skips it if it sees something it does not like.

So to me it seems like before you get to the point you are checking you get an exception that causes it to go to the finally block and dispose your object.

Comment: Thanks, but would this not then cause the same error then with just MySealedClass msc = new MySealedClass()? (No using statement)

Comment: yes, tt should. Do the constructor only have the single line of code you have mentioned above? The thing is that in addition to the constructor, other initalizers will run to. So anything you have like `public SomeClass VarName = new SomeThing()`.

Comment: My best guess is that something you set up using DllImport crashes and caused the exception. Does it work in IIS without the using block, or did you try it without the using block in another environment?

Comment: If that gets you nowwhere, I think we will need to see the entire code from `MySealedClass` to find your problem.

Comment: The constructor is just the single line and there are no other initialisers. I'll try it on IIS without the using block now. When you say different environment do you mean something other IIS?

Comment: Yes, I mean something other than IIS. But I still think we need the code of that class to be able to help you. You can get some strange errors sometimes with DllImport/pInvoke.

Comment: I didn't have any luck by remove the using braces. I've edited the post by adding some code from the relevant classes. Have you got any ideas how I would test if it actually runs the external dll?

Comment: I now think the problem I'm experiencing is hardware specific. I now know I have component I can't use and perhaps this is causing undefined (or mis-understood on my part) behaviour. I'm marked this as answers because you confirmed my question of what is happening inside the using statement. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Good luck in solving your issue. I also thinks that your issue lies with the DllImport not working according to how you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to MSDN Documentation, "The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object."

Why don't you debug the unsafe code you mentioned within the using block. May be the exception thrown within the external dll is causing a call to Displose() method?

Comment: unfortunately all runs fine in visual studio so debugging doesn't help. I've resorted to throwing exceptions at various places, rebuilding and calling from the browser.